# Filipino versus Tagalog

Tags: dialects, language-families

Is the only difference between Filipino and Tagalog the alphabet used to transcribe the various associated words?-Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Filipino* is a [standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_language) register/dialect of Tagalog language.

There exist other, non-standard, dialects of Tagalog. Each of those have differences to each other (e.g., if they were absolutely matching, they would be not considered different ones).

The Wikipedia article on Tagalog lists [several important differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagalog_language#Dialects) between the dialects of Tagalog language, including differences to the standard register (Filipino). This includes phonology (glottal stops and consonants), morphology (suffixes), and more.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to furnish a complete listing of Tagalog dialects in your answer?

Comment: @JackMaddington, I'm afraid there's no such list at all. [This article](http://www.101languages.net/tagalog/dialects.html) says, *"At present, no comprehensive dialectology has been done in the Tagalog-speaking regions, though there have been descriptions in the form of dictionaries and grammars on various Tagalog dialects. Ethnologue lists Lubang, Manila, Marinduque, Bataan, Batangan, Bulacan, Tanay-Paete, and Tayabas as dialects of Tagalog."*

Answer (score 2):

[Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/subgroups/tagalog-1) states Tagalog as consisting of two branches, Filipino (fil) and Tagalog (tgl).
So "Tagalog" seems to be ambiguous (or rather underspecified), referring to both the more general and the more specific branch.